# How do I deploying website by PythonAnywhere.com

Tags: django, web, deployment, pythonanywhere

I got this error message.

[image]

So I entered setting.py file and change like this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]', '.pythonanywhere.com']
```

and Reload my site.

but nothing changed.

[image]

at this time, I changed the code like this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['heenamkang.pythonanywhere.com']
```

and then I got this error message. this is evidence that change is reflected.

[image]

[image]

But I still can't enter the `'heenamkang.anywhere.com'`

Third and fourth images are captured at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', u'heenamkang.pythonanywhere.com']
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got same message that I received(my 2nd screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Your first traceback shows your app running on PythonAnywhere. Other one shows the app running on your local machine.

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'heenamkang.pythonanywhere.com']` should be enough to make it work in both environments.

Comment: I tried this, but I got same message that I received(my 2nd screenshot)

Comment: Are you sure you reloaded the code after making the change?  Your third screenshot suggests that the addition of `127.0.0.1` to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` had not been applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `.` before your pythonanywhere url.

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.heenamkang.pythonanywhere.com']`

Comment: Thank you so much, but I got same message that I received(my 2nd screenshot)